# SQL Server : CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a SQL statement to check where condition if the column is null, it will do other condition. Below is my example:

```
SELECT  
    REPLACE(xxShip.Shipment_Date, '/', '-') AS ShipDate,xxShip.Customer,
    xxShip.TravelSheetNo
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TravelSheetNo ORDER BY created_on DESC) AS shipwocode,
         ShipDate, ShipTime, Shipment_Date, 
         Customer, Product_no, TravelSheetNo,
         [status], ProcessLotNo
     FROM  
         xxDEShipment) xxShip
WHERE 
    xxShip.shipwocode = 1
    AND xxShip.TravelSheetNo = 'ABC'
    --here i need to check the condition----------------------------
    AND (CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(xxShip.Shipment_Date,'') != '' OR xxShip.Shipment_Date != '' 
              THEN
                 xxShip.Shipment_Date IS NULL OR xxShip.Shipment_Date = '' 
              ELSE
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, xxShip.Shipment_Date) >=  @DATESTART and CONVERT(DATETIME, xxShip.Shipment_Date) <=  @DATEEND
         END)
```

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be something like this:

```
AND(
     (ISNULL(xxShip.Shipment_Date,'') <> '' AND 
      CONVERT(DATETIME, xxShip.Shipment_Date) >=  @DATESTART AND 
      CONVERT(DATETIME, xxShip.Shipment_Date) <=  @DATEEND
     ) 
     OR ISNULL(xxShip.Shipment_Date,'') == ''
   )
```

Note that storing dates as strings is a bad practice.

Comment: hi Giorgi..i have try your code but still have this error: 
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. Please help

Comment: Show me the sample data of column `Shipment_Date`. `select top 1 Shipment_Date from xxDEShipment where ISDATE(Shipment_Date) = 0`

Comment: hi giorgi..it works..the issue i cant use your code before because 1 of my data in that column is in dd/MM/yyyy..after i change it to yyyy/MM/dd, it works. thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select dates between `@DATESTART` and `@DATEEND` **or** null **or** empty date, use below:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, NULLIF(xxShip.Shipment_Date, '')), @DATESTART) 
    BETWEEN @DATESTART AND @DATEEND
```

Comment: Hi Eric..just try your code but still have this error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. Please help

Comment: @eikaz I think you should analysis the values of your Shipment_Date column. `SELECT * FROM xxDEShipment WHERE ISDATE(Shipment_Date) = 0 AND Shipment_Date <> ''`

Comment: hi eric..your code works..the issue i cant use your code before because 1 of my data in that column is in dd/MM/yyyy..after i change it to yyyy/MM/dd, it works. thanks again..